# Use Custom gradle plugin module in another module

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, build, gradle-plugin

I am developing a custom plugin that I want to be able to deploy to a repository at a later stage so I've created a stand alone module for it.

Before I do any formal TDD on it, I wanna do certain exploratory tests manually so, I've created a demo module that uses the given plugin in.

The only way I've found so far to do this was to deploy the plugin into a local repository and then import it on the other module. But this is very tedious and it's quite easy to forget to deploy it.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this more straight forward.

Answer (score 7):

#### Update(2020-09-07):

It's possible to use `includeBuild("plugin/module")` to add a module into the classpath of the project so the plugin can be applied. With one caveat, it doesn't work yet if you want to apply it on `settings.gradle[.kts]` as I found out on this [thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/composite-build-includebuild-and-use-within-settings-gradle/23761/3).

#### Old answer:

The best solution I've found was to include the folders of the plugin module as part of the buildSrc module (used for local scripting) within it's source sets like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy.srcDirs += "../custom-plugin/src/main/groovy"
        resources.srcDirs += "../custom-plugin/src/main/resources"
    }
}
```

This will let you use the plugin as if it was in the remote repository but without having to deploy it every time. Next unit tests :)

Comment: Where to include these? At the root or inside any blocks?

Comment: On the root of the gradle build file for the `buildSrc` module

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1:

If you are using gradle 3.1 or later, you can use the [composite build feature](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).
Build your standalone module like this: `gradle build --include-build /path/to/plugin-root`

Assuming you run this command from the root of a standalone gradle project that applies the plugin, this would first build the plugin, then build your standalone project and apply the just built plugin to it.

### Option 2:

If you use an older gradle version (which does not support composite builds), you can apply [the maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) to your plugin project. This defines the `install` task, which you can now call by running `gradle install` in the root of your plugin project.
This task builds your plugin and puts the resulting `jar` in a local cache directory (on Linux the default path is `~/.m2`).
Notice that after every change you make in the plugin code, you have to run `gradle install` again.

Now, for your standalone project to use the local plugin `jar`, you need to edit the build script and put `mavenLocal()` under `buildscript.repositories`. Make sure that `mavenLocal()` is above anything else in the `repositories` block.

Example of the buildscript block of your standalone project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.mycompany.plugins:my-awsome-plugin:1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is what I mentioned on my question that I was trying to avoid. And Option 1 seems like almost as much trouble. :( Thanks though.

Comment: I don't see why option 1 seems like almost as much trouble. It is actually a huge improvement. You don't have to `install` the plugin anymore after every change. All you have to do is add a single parameter to the `gradle build` command of the demo module. I personally feel that after I started using the composite-build feature while developing a plugin, I am able to see the results of my changes much faster and my life is generally much better :)

Comment: Sorry, i meant against what I suggested on my answer